# LWP::Useragent timeout with HTTP::Headers

Tags: perl

I wrote a little script that connectts to an URL, posts some xml data and waits for response, so far so good, I need to set timeout but I think I do it wrong because I get this error message:

> Can't locate object method "timeout" via package "HTTP::Headers" at
>   /usr/share/perl5/HTTP/Message.pm line 644.

this is my little code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $msg =<< "EOT";
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
EOT

my $uri = "http://www.myhostexample.com/script";
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $uri);
$request->content_type("text/xml");
$request->content($msg);

my $response = LWP::UserAgent->new->request($request);
$response->timeout(10);
#print $response->content . "\n"; # debug

if ($response->content =~ /<?xml/s) {

    print "OK!\n";
}
else {

    print "BAD!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set timeout for LWP::UserAgent.

```
...
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->timeout(10);

my $response = $ua->request($request);
...
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! Works flawlessly now. I did set timeout in "HTTP::Headers" and not "LWP::UserAgent" as I should have. Thanks!